# Loading bar while image loads from getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading, getelementbyid

Below I have some code for a comic website I'm maintaining. When you click various buttons or select a page from the drop down menu the image changes to the corresponding image. However the image remains on the previous image until the new one has loaded. Is there any way I can add a loading bar or one of the spinning circle things until it has happened?

FYI, I'm not heaps advanced with JS, and this is my own code creation. Help much appreciated.

```
// Drop Down Menu, next and previous buttons

// Buttons
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dd = $('#HailComic');
    var max_len = dd.find('option').length;
    $('#nextpage').click(function () {
        var x = dd.find('option:selected').index();
        if (max_len == x + 1) x = -1;
        dd.find('option').eq(x + 1).prop('selected', true);
        document.getElementById("hail_image").src="images/comic/hail_" + HailComic.options[HailComic.selectedIndex].value + ".jpg";
    });
    $('#previouspage').click(function () {
        var x = dd.find('option:selected').index();
        if (0 == x + 1) x = max_len;
        dd.find('option').eq(x - 1).prop('selected', true);
        document.getElementById("hail_image").src="images/comic/hail_" + HailComic.options[HailComic.selectedIndex].value + ".jpg";
    });
    $('#lastpage').click(function () {
        var x = max_len;
        dd.find('option').eq(x - 1).prop('selected', true);
        document.getElementById("hail_image").src="images/comic/hail_" + HailComic.options[HailComic.selectedIndex].value + ".jpg";
    });
    $('#firstpage').click(function () {
        dd.find('option').eq(0).prop('selected', true);
        document.getElementById("hail_image").src="images/comic/hail_001.jpg";
    });
});




// List Changing
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Select
    var changeHailImage = function () { 
    document.getElementById('hail_image').src = "images/comic/hail_" + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value + ".jpg"
    }

    var HailList = document.getElementById('HailComic');
    HailList.addEventListener('change', changeHailImage, false);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an use `img.load()`   function to achieve this. Please check the pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvwWWj

```
var changeHailImage = function () { 
    document.getElementById('hail_image').src = 'loading.gif';//get a loading image
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "images/comic/hail_" + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value + ".jpg";
    img.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('hail_image').src = img.src;
   }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!